I can't clone projects from my companys git from my new mac
2 days ago I replace my pc with a new mac and trying to set it up for my work, but I can't clone a project from my company's local repository. I don't know what to do at this point can u guys help here is the list that what I already do:

downloaded forticlient to connect to my company's git repository through chrome, but when I tried Safari it said 'server cannot be found'

downloaded brew and install git and config my email git name and password

tried both ssh and https and both didn't work. I even tried with personal token, didn't work

Received an error message that says fatal: unable to access 'https://git.******.git/': Could not resolve host: git..com.

entered my ssh key to my company's git

hanger my DNS and tried different Wi-Fi's, didn't work either


It was worked perfect on my old Windows computer can u guys help i don't know what to do at this point. Thanks

If your IT department uses Fortinet, then you should talk to your IT department about being able to use the corporate VPN.  Nowhere in your posting do you say that you properly configured FortiClient and connected to the VPN.

I went to the company today and have the same issue. I don't think the problem is vpn . I connected to wifi and have the same issue and worse. Now i can't even connected to git through chrome.

Some works require VPN with zero trust configurations, some work networks need web proxies, some block ICMP. It’s really not productive to ask us all to guess your needs in this unique case where we’re not in a position to help you.

Everything looks to be networking issue. I would try cloning a public repository and since you used homebrew, you know that already works.
You could also sign up for a well known free git account and validate you didn’t miss some step like generating ssh key pairs that is needed for your work.

https://gitlab.com/-/trial_registrations/new
https://github.com/join?plan=free

Both of those have copious beginners tutorials available.
More likely, you just need support from work on solving your network issue. They will tell you which ports are open on the git server, if you can use ping to check connectivity or how that network is configured (some may block ICMP echo making ping tests pointless)
In almost any case (but not all), you should be able to browse your repo with a web browser to confirm that’s set up or put that in your ticket to support and test with your PC to see if there are web proxies to configure.
Open a support ticket with work to get the network setup as we can’t guess how they want you to connect with the details you provided. There’s nothing wrong with your git setup on the Mac. It’s ready to go once you can connect to your repo and enter correct credentials.

Thanks for your comment. i did all the steps you recomended but still no results and also i tried a public repository and it worked . I think the problem is FortiClient i did have some issues from the start with FortiClient but i thought i'll fixed it .

You confirm my suspicion. Git is ready to go on your Mac. See if IT will tell you how to use the macOS VPN client entering the endpoint manually instead of fighting the Fortinet client?

Update: So i went to the company today and connected to the wifi and still have the same issue and worse. Now i can't even connected to git through chrome. I tried ping the server didnt have any response any ideas ?

What does your support organization say @MustafaAyfer

If you are on your corporate network and should be able to reach the server, and can't, talk to your local IT.  git notwithstanding, you should be able to ping the server.
